# Can access postgres via command line, but rake/rails commands do not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Trying to setup postgres for a rails app in a local VM with vagrant. I can get into postgres shell with the vagrant user no problem:

```
psql -d postgres -U vagrant
```

However, when running command such as `rake db:create`, I get an error:

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"vagrant_d", "username"=>"vagrant"}
The driver encountered an unknown error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "vagrant"
```

My yaml file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: vagrant_d
  username: vagrant

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: vagrant_t
  username: vagrant
```

I have setup the pg_hba.conf file as such:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Any ideas?

Note this is a debian machine with postgresql 9.1

Comment: create password and grant priveleges to `vagrant` user `alter role vagrant superuser createdb replication;`

Comment: Does the vagrant user have a password? I'm not sure if you can use the database with rake with no password for it.

Comment: Make sure you are in the right environment. Override RAILS_ENV if required

Comment: @Monk_Code setting a password & altering the role did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create password and grant privileges to vagrant user:

```
=# alter user vagrant with password '';
=# alter role vagrant superuser createdb replication;
```

Comment: Just for others to reference, i set password via: `alter user vagrant with password ''`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `host: localhost` to the database configuration. That forces it to connect via TCP/IP, otherwise it may try to connect via socket.

Comment: Nope, the host shouldnt be required. Also doing this with the psql command causes an auth error: `psql -U vagrant -h localhost -d vagrant_d`

Comment: psql command line will usually connect via socket, so maybe the problem is related.